# What could prevent the Mods menu from appearing?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge

I'm on Mac OSX. **I can't get the mods menu to show in minecraft**.
I tried to follow: 
http://www.instructables.com/id/Python-coding-for-Minecraft/

I've installed

forge-1.9.4-12.17.0.2051-installer.jar

I do see a forge profile in the launcher (launcher version 1.6.70). I edited the profile to use version release 1.9.4. Minecraft starts just fine, but nowhere do I see a mods menu item. I can find "options->Resource Packs..." but nothing about mods. "/py" in the console results in "unknown command".

From the launcher, "open game dir" brings me to

/Users/jeff/Library/Application Support/minecraft

which has mods/1.10, mods/1.9.4 and mcpipy/ with lots of python files.

I also retried the whole process with forge-1.11.2 and I get the same results.

Could anybody indicate me how to debug this further ? What are the steps to figure out why the mods menu is not showing ?

Thanks !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about support for a modded version of Minecraft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing the profile that Forge created for you to use 1.9.4 broke the profile — doing that tells the profile to run *unmodded* 1.9.4!

The profile Forge adds for you already has the Forge-modded 1.9.4 version selected and will work without needing you to change anything. Just leave it alone and launch it.